# PHP Variable being overwritten in if statement

Tags: php

Below is my code.
The posted statement is working & bringing variables through.

However, the if statement `$table="1"` is overwriting the `$table` variable with the value 1... so the check is always true.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thank you!

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);


    $table = $_POST['origintable'];
    $database = $_POST['origindatabase'];

    if ($table = "1") { 
        echo "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Database name: <b>$database</b> Table name:<b>$table</b>.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Have a good night!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if ($table == "1")`

Comment: That is an assignment operation not a comparison.

Comment: change to this `$table == 1`

Comment: That is an assignment operation not a comparison. It succeeds in the if because assignment expressions evaluate to their value. So your code check if 1 was a truthy value after assigning it to $table

Comment: That is sort of the expected behavior with the code you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `==`  operator because `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is comparison operator or you can use `===` if you want to check same type with comparison example given below

```
if ($table == "1") {
```

example

```
if (1 == "1") {
    // it will return true
}
if (1 === "1") {
     // it will return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, compare ==  operator

```
if ($table == "1") { 
    echo "<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Database name: <b>$database</b> Table name:<b>$table</b>.";
}
else {
    echo "Have a good night!";
}
```